# Cannot install package on rooted device : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI

Tags: android, android-studio

This is what I see when I try to install my app on my device (I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2):

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_s7500-cf994b04
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\Testaqua\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.administrator.testaqua
Installing com.example.administrator.testaqua
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.administrator.testaqua"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.administrator.testaqua
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
```

What in the seven hells does this error mean?

[Edited] I installed my app on another rooted device, and it worked; it seems the problem is my device, android studio is running fine.

Comment: is it a rooted device ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this [blog](http://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/android-adb-install_failed_invalid_uri/) try this :

Change permission of `/data/local` to `rwxrwxrwx` (normally it must be `rwxrwxrw-`)

i.e. grant execution privileges to all users.

Comment: Change permission of /data/local wasn't enough:I had to change /data/local/tmp too.
Thanks a lot, mate!

Comment: adb shell; cd /data; chmod 777 local

Answer (score 20):

I get similar error message, I fixed it by passing the absolute path instead of filename, e.g. inside `adb shell`, this command will shows:

```
shell@example:/sdcard $ pm install -r -d app-release.apk
        pkg: app-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
```

Change it to absolute path fixed that error message, e.g.:

`pm install -r -d /sdcard/app-release.apk`

**[Second reason]**

Another reason is the file not exist. It happen when I interrupt `adb push <apk> /sdcard/` by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> recently. Re-push apk **twice** required.

**[Third reason]**

This error occurred if the apk reside `/mnt/runtime/default/<thumb_drive_mounted_directory>`, I have to move the apk to `/sdcard/` first to install.

Answer (score 2):

symptoms: `

```
$ adb install xyz.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/xyz.apk
    pkg: cat
    ver: /data/local/tmp/xyz.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
```

solution:

check if u have allow installation from unknown sources enabled :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the reason is dir and file permission.
Android seems to use another user to access the dir and file.

```
chmod 775 /data/local/tmp/somedir         ==> rwxrwx<b>r-x</b><br>
chmod 774 /data/local/tmp/somedir/a.apk   ==> rwxrwx<b>r</b>--<br>
```

The above setting will be OK!

Answer (score 0):

It happened with my Flutter app once. Removing apk file from your-project-name\build\app\outputs\apk\debug and running the app again solved the issue. Before this issue happened, I closed running Flutter app manually from the phone while it was still attached to terminal and running.